# Maven modules - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, parent-pom

I can't run this... Anyone what could I be doing wrong?

```
modules
 | server
 |   |_com
 |    |_test
 |     |_app
 |      |_Main.java
 | |_pom.xml (server_pom)
 | comum
 |   |_com
 |    |_test
 |     |_app
 |      |_interfaces
 |       |_ServerInterface.java
 | |_pom.xml (comum_pom)
 | client
 |   |_com
 |    |_test
 |     |_app
 |      |_Main.java
 | |_pom.xml (client_pom)
 |_pom.xml (modules_pom)
```

**modules_pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    

    <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>    
    <packaging>pom</packaging>            
    
    <modules>
        <module>comum</module>
        <module>server</module>
        <module>client</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**server_pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <groupId>com.test.app.server</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>

    <!-- Parent POM -->
    <parent>
        <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>        
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent> 
       
    <!-- Comun / Interfaces -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.app.comum</groupId>
            <artifactId>comum</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>            

</project>
```

**comum_pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <groupId>com.test.app.comum</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>comum</artifactId>

    <!-- Parent POM -->
    <parent>
        <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>        
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>    
                    
</project>
```

**client_pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <groupId>com.test.app.client</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>client</artifactId>

    <!-- Parent POM -->
    <parent>
        <artifactId>modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>        
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent> 
       
    <!-- Comun / Interfaces -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.app.comum</groupId>
            <artifactId>comum</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>            

</project>
```

**When I run the `mvn package`:**

```
mvn package

.
.
.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] modules                                                            [pom]
[INFO] comum                                                              [jar]
[INFO] server                                                             [jar]
[INFO] client                                                             [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< com.test.app:modules >----------------
.
.
.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for modules 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] modules ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.014 s]
[INFO] comum .............................................. SUCCESS [  2.084 s]
[INFO] server ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.098 s]
[INFO] client ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.114 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

But...

```
java -cp server/target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.app.server.Main 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/app/comum/interfaces/ServerInterface
```

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the last version of the dependency (comum) that is on the "server" module, was not installed in the m2 directory.

Run `mvn install` on "comum" module and be sure to the existed jar file that is on m2 folder has the compiled "_ServerInterface".